# How to return value in anonymous function?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
new EventHandler((s, seder) => lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id));
```

And function `lnkSynEvent_Click()`:

```
private string lnkSynEvent_Click(object s, EventArgs e, string id)
{
   return "ok";
}
```

I need to get "ok" in:

```
EventHandler((s, seder) => lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id) { // Here });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get "ok" in"?

Comment: To get value string "ok". The answer in bewlow is right

Comment: @Daniel So you didn't know how to store the result of a function call in a variable?  If so, you shouldn't be using anonymous methods yet.  Focus on the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to capture the return value of the `lnkSynEvent_Click` function as a variable inside your anonymous function, just do something like:

```
new EventHandler((s, sender) => { string result = lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id); /* your code */ });
```

...or with nicer layout:

```
new EventHandler((s, sender) =>
{
    string result = lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id);
    // Code
});
```

Comment: It does not work, it gives me error, that it should be static